# 3-legged authentication with Twitter API and Tweepy in Python problem

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twitter-oauth

Here is the context of what I want to do:
Automate following certain profiles on Twitter with an account that is different from my Twitter developer account. For that I read that I need 3-legged OAuth.

Here is my code:

```
import tweepy


consumer_key = "XXX"
consumer_secret = "XXX"

oauth1_user_handler = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(
    consumer_key, consumer_secret,
    callback="callback url"
)
print(oauth1_user_handler.get_authorization_url(signin_with_twitter=True))
```

Following the link printed I am able to authenticate my app using the Twitter account and then get something like this:

```
https://my_callback_url?oauth_token=XXX&oauth_verifier=XXXX
```

Following Tweepy's documentation, I should be able to put this `oauth_verifier` there:

```
access_token, access_token_secret = oauth1_user_handler.get_access_token(
    "Verifier (oauth_verifier) here"
)
```

However, it is not correct, because every time I run my code I need to authenticate again and get a new `oauth_verifier` token.
On the Twitter developer portal everything is setup with this OAuth 1 permission and putting a callback URL and website URL was mandatory. I don't know what else to do.
That's where I am stuck.

I am following Tweepy's documentation [here](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/authentication.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to reuse the access token and secret, not the verifier.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your answer. I already have those from Twitter developer portal. But it is not linked to my other account.

Comment: You're getting the ones for whoever is authenticating, with `OAuth1UserHandler.get_access_token`.

Comment: Now I am stuck with this error: tweepy.errors. `TweepyException: Token request failed with code 401, response was '{"errors":[{"code":89,"message":"Invalid or expired token."}]}'.`

Comment: I believe if you generate a new access token and secret, the old ones are revoked.